# Google Play Android App error

Tags: android

I have a problem uploading the application to Google Play me that the icon does not have the correct size 48x48, I have all 3 sizes correctly in their respective folders.
You can see the capture of the error and the code referencing the icon. I have every icon size, as shown in 36.48 and 74 web pix in your folder.

What could be my problem?

[image: Code reference icon]

[image: Error Google Play]

Comment: Make sure you are using PNG Image format not jpg or any other.what is extension of you image

Comment: Do you have default folder drawable/ or only more specific types drawable-hdpi/, drawable-mdpi/ etc.? Try add 48x48 icon to drawable/.

Comment: try this link http://my-instinct-was-wrong.com/2011/02/26/the-icon-for-your-application-is-not-valid-please-use-a-48x48-png/

Comment: My extension is .png, and i have a folders drawable-hdpi/, drawable-mdpi/, drawable-ldpi/ with respective size icon into.

Comment: thanks Akki, the same problem that url. :-)